# Difficulty to understand PHP POST to REST API - mixed array and objects

Tags: php, arrays, rest, object, parameters

I'm trying to POST data to a REST API.

On Postman I can POST with success, the JSON body is:

```
{
  "version": 0,
  "roles": {
    "customer": {
    }
  },
  "person": {
     "firstName": "Inge",
     "lastName": "Musterfrau"
  },
  "emailAddresses" :{
    "private" : [
      "email@domain.com"
    ]
  },
"addresses": {
    "billing": [
      {
        "supplement": null,
        "street": "aaa",
        "zip": "12345",
        "city": "Berlin",
        "countryCode": "DE"
      }
    ]
  }
        
}
```

My problem is on addresses billing. I don't know how to create the object/array correctly so the API accept it.

I'm build the parameters on PHO like bellow:

```
$billingAddr = array(
                    "supplement" => $billingAddress["streetDetails"],
                    "street" => $billingAddress["street"],
                    "zip" => $billingAddress["zipCode"],
                    "city" => $billingAddress["city"],
                    "countryCode" => $billingAddress["country"],
                );
                $params = [
                    "version"       => 0,
                    "roles"         => $roles,
                    "person"        => $person,
                    "emailAddresses"  => $emailAddresses,
                    "addresses"     => [
                        "billing"  => $billingAddr
                    ]
                ];
```

I get an error: "missing_entity - addresses - validation_failure".

I believe my issue is creating the mixed Object addresses, array billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, going strictly by the PHP example, doing a `json_encode`'d output of that shows that the structure is not quite the same at the addresses.

Note that I do not have the data for most of the rest of the json info from the PHP example, so the output examples below are strictly focused on the `addresses` section.

```
Before JSON change:

echo json_encode($params, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

{
    "version": 0,
    "roles": null,
    "person": null,
    "emailAddresses": null,
    "addresses": {
        "billing": {
            "supplement": null,
            "street": null,
            "zip": null,
            "city": null,
            "countryCode": null
        }
    }
}
```

... in that, note that the billing does not have the `[]` characters like what is sent using postman.

No worries though, it's an easy fix. The addresses part should be changed to get an array of billing addresses, like so:

```
"addresses"     => [
    "billing"  => [$billingAddr]
]
```

Then running a recheck with that change applied shows:

```
After JSON change:

echo json_encode($params, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

{
    "version": 0,
    "roles": null,
    "person": null,
    "emailAddresses": null,
    "addresses": {
        "billing": [
            {
                "supplement": null,
                "street": null,
                "zip": null,
                "city": null,
                "countryCode": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

That should help to achieve the expected format.

Here's the [fiddle example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=1444d61654179a4bf9901dab2c66df9c&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57) in case you might need another PHP version to check. The fiddle default is 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Object properties and associative arrays are easy to access/declare directly; however, when you need to push data into indexed subarrays, you can to use `[]` syntax or `array_push()`.

If you want to build a bit more maintainability in this code, you can build the variable-length subarrays as individual variables and then feed them into the master array just before json_encoding.

```
$version = 0;
$roles = ['customer' => []];
$person = [
    'firstName' => 'Inge',
    'lastName' => 'Musterfrau'
];
$emailAddresses = [
    'private' => [
        'email@domain.com',
    ]
];
$billingAddresses[] = [
    'supplement' => $billingAddress["streetDetails"],
    'street' => $billingAddress["street"],
    'zip' => $billingAddress["zipCode"],
    'city' => $billingAddress["city"],
    'countryCode' => $billingAddress["country"]
];
// use $billingAddresses[] again to push another subarray into $billing

$data = [
    'version' => $version,
    'roles' => $roles,
    'person' => $person,
    'emailAddresses' => $emailAddresses,
    'addresses' => [
        'billing' => $billingAddresses
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create your array/json :

```
    $arr['version'] = "0";
    $arr['roles']['customer'] = [];
    $arr['person']['firstName'] = "Inge";
    $arr['person']['lastName'] = "Musterfrau";
    $arr['emailAddresses']['private'][] = "email@domain.com";
    $arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['supplement'] = "";
    $arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['street'] = "aaa";
    $arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['zip'] = "12345";
    $arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['city'] = "Berlin";
    $arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['countryCode'] = "DE";
    
    $newJson = json_encode($arr);
```

Afterwards you json_encode it and voila the perfect json and very simple!

*The best and easiest way to look at a json (to my opinion at least:) is as an array! (no shame in using the browser and echo "<pre>" here!) - We'll build an identical array and json it up back!*

Once we see the json as an array we build the same in a very simple way **here is the whole code example with step by step:**

```
<?php

/*Our original json */
$json = '{
  "version": 0,
  "roles": {
    "customer": {
    }
  },
  "person": {
     "firstName": "Inge",
     "lastName": "Musterfrau"
  },
  "emailAddresses" :{
    "private" : [
      "email@domain.com"
    ]
  },
"addresses": {
    "billing": [
      {
        "supplement": null,
        "street": "aaa",
        "zip": "12345",
        "city": "Berlin",
        "countryCode": "DE"
      }
    ]
  }

}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
echo '<pre>';
/* original array */
echo "original array: ";
print_r($array);
echo '<pre>';
/* now lets create the same array with less fuss?! */

$arr['version'] = "0";
$arr['roles']['customer'] = [];
$arr['person']['firstName'] = "Inge";
$arr['person']['lastName'] = "Musterfrau";
$arr['emailAddresses']['private'][] = "email@domain.com";
$arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['supplement'] = "";
$arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['street'] = "aaa";
$arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['zip'] = "12345";
$arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['city'] = "Berlin";
$arr['addresses']['billing'][0]['countryCode'] = "DE";

/* the new array: */
echo "our newly created array: ";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '<pre>';
/* back to json */
echo "new Json: ";
echo '<pre>';
$newJson = json_encode($arr);
print_r($newJson);
```

This will return:

```
original array: Array
(
    [version] => 0
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [person] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => Inge
            [lastName] => Musterfrau
        )

    [emailAddresses] => Array
        (
            [private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => email@domain.com
                )

        )

    [addresses] => Array
        (
            [billing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [supplement] => 
                            [street] => aaa
                            [zip] => 12345
                            [city] => Berlin
                            [countryCode] => DE
                        )

                )

        )

)
our newly created array: 
Array
(
    [version] => 0
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [person] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => Inge
            [lastName] => Musterfrau
        )

    [emailAddresses] => Array
        (
            [private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => email@domain.com
                )

        )

    [addresses] => Array
        (
            [billing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [supplement] => 
                            [street] => aaa
                            [zip] => 12345
                            [city] => Berlin
                            [countryCode] => DE
                        )

                )

        )

)
new Json: 
{"version":"0","roles":{"customer":[]},"person":{"firstName":"Inge","lastName":"Musterfrau"},"emailAddresses":{"private":["email@domain.com"]},"addresses":{"billing":[{"supplement":"","street":"aaa","zip":"12345","city":"Berlin","countryCode":"DE"}]}}
```

Building arrays can be very simple this way - almost feels linear! :)